El manager de mi Docker Swarm se libero sin razon alguna, me pide hacer un " docker swarm init " ¿Si lo hago se pierden servicios y nodos agregados?
Mi pregunta es: ¿Como solucionar sin perder servicios y nodos que ya estaban configurados dentro del manager? Por ahora todos los servicios corren sin problema, pero cuando intento ejecutar docker service ls me regresa: Error response from daemon: This node is not a swarm manager. Use "docker swarm init" or "docker swarm join" to connect this node to swarm and try again. y no puedo crear nuevos servicios ni modificar los existentes.
Docker Version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           25.0.2
 API version:       1.44
 Go version:        go1.21.6
 Git commit:        29cf629
 Built:             Thu Feb  1 00:22:57 2024
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          25.0.2
  API version:      1.44 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.21.6
  Git commit:       fce6e0c
  Built:            Thu Feb  1 00:22:57 2024
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.28
  GitCommit:        ae07eda36dd25f8a1b98dfbf587313b99c0190bb
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.12
  GitCommit:        v1.1.12-0-g51d5e94
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0


Si al ejecutar
docker node ls

obtienes el mensaje:

Error response from daemon: This node is not a swarm manager. Use
"docker swarm init" or "docker swarm join" to connect this node to
swarm and try again.

indica que no tienes acceso o el nodo no es parte de un swarm,, lo que tienes que realizar es precisamente lo que indica el mensaje, reconfigurar el nodo como manager:
docker swarm init


Hola @Jorgesys, antes de todo Gracias por responder.
Te comento que este nodo ya era parte del Swarm y su rol era de Manager, cuando intento
docker swarm init
me retorna esto Error response from daemon: This node is already part of a swarm. Use "docker swarm leave" to leave this swarm and join another one.
Mi temor es perder todo si hago el leave.

Veo que realizaste docker swarm init --force-new-cluster

Si, me soluciono el problema, porque docker swarm init me pedia que hiciera un docker swarm leave antes y eso si mataria toda la configuración anterior.

Con ayuda en otros foros conseguí solucionar la problemática de esta forma.
Verifique los errores en los logs con esto: journalctl -xfu docker.service
Al diagnosticar problemas en SWARM, docker info muestra la lista de direcciones IP de los Managers, esto confirmará si swarm ha perdido el número mínimo de Managers necesarios.
En mi caso, este era el único Manager desde el cual podía intentar recuperar el Clúster, entonces ejecute docker swarm init --force-new-cluster lo que restableció a que fuera el único Manager para swarm, esta acción preservo el estado existente del swarm: servicios, configuraciones, etc., así como los join-tokens para que los workers se volvieran a unir automáticamente.
¡Espero sea de ayuda, Saludos!
